# Ubdefined reference to PathRemoveFileSpec

Tags: c++, windows, sfml

Estaba tratando de hacer un código que permite capturar el path donde se encuentra el programa, teniendo en cuenta el sistema operativo que usas, pero me da el siguiente error:

```
undefined refenrece to PathRemoveFileSpec
```

Aquí el código:

```
#pragma once

#define RUNNING_WINDOWS

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

namespace Utils
{
    #ifdef RUNNING_WINDOWS
    #define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
    
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <Shlwapi.h>
    
    inline std::string GetWorkingDirectory()
    {
        HMODULE hModule = GetModuleHandle(nullptr);
        
        if(hModule)
        {
            char path[256];
            GetModuleFileName(hModule, path, sizeof(path));
            PathRemoveFileSpec(path);
            strcat_s(path,"\\");
            return std::string(path);
        }
        return "";
    }
    
    #elif defined RUNNING_LINUX
    
    #include <unistd.h>
    
    inline std::string GetWorkingDirectory()
    {
        char cwd[1024];
        if(getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)) != nullptr)
        {
            return std::string(cwd) + std::string("/");
        }
        return "";
    }
    #endif
}
```

¿Alguna idea?. En teoría la función está incluida en la biblioteca Shlwapi.h, que está incluida, ¿o está depreciada esa función?

Comment: Que esté deprecada significa que no se recomienda su uso. No necesariamente que no se pueda usar más porque no forme más parte del código.

Comment: Asegúrate de agregar la librería [`shlwapi`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-pathremovefilespeca) a las opciones de compilación

Comment: Como ves, en la línea 11 (más menos) del código está incluida la librería

Comment: Si, está incluida. A lo que me refiero es a indicar en las opciones de compilación que se debe linkear con ella. No sé que IDE o compilador estás usando. Si estás en Visual Studio comparte una captura de la configuración del proyecto de Linker -> Input

Comment: Utilizo Codeblocks 20.03 en Windows 8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A la hora de usar librerías en C++, tu código debe contener declaradas las funciones que quieras usar de la librería. De este modo, el linker se encargará de buscar una definición para ellas.

Podrías declararlas manualmente y funcionaría (siempre que las declaraciones coincidan con las definiciones). Pero lo típico es que el creador de una librería distribuya con ella uno o más archivos .h con todas la funcionalidad declarada en ella.

Adicionalmente debes indicarle al compilador la librería dónde se encuentran las definiciones.

Según la documentación de [`PathRemoveFileSpec`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-pathremovefilespeca), deberías incluir `shlwapi.h` (que ya lo has hecho) y linkear la librería `shlwapi`.

No estoy familiarizado con CodeBlocks, pero basándome en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5881751/13419694):

Deberías darle clic derecho al proyecto. Seleccionar `Build options`. Luego `Linker Settings`. Finalmente tocas `Add` y escribes el nombre de la librería. (`shlwapi` en este caso).

Algunas capturas del proceso tomadas por el autor de la respuesta mencionada:

[image: Imagen tomada de https://stackoverflow.com/a/5881751/13419694]